# How to get records in json format using Entity Framework in Web API

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I need to fetch the table records in json format from a Web API. I'm not able to get multiple records in json format.

[image: table data]

Code:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetGPS()
{
    try
    {
        using (smartpondEntities DB = new smartpondEntities())
        {

                var gps = DB.GPS.ToList();
                var gpsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gps);
                return Ok(gpsJson);
        }       
    }
```

Response

```
{"success":true,"gps":{"id":1,"lat":"8888","longitude":"88888"}}
```

Datatype

```
public partial class GP
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> updatedTime { get; set; }
    public string lat { get; set; }
    public string longitude { get; set; }
    public string deviceid { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please add formatting to your question and make the question in general more verbose.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can get the results in a list and then serialize it into Json like below.

To Convert:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var gpsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gps);
```

To return:
1.

```
 var gps = DB.GPS.ToList();
 return Ok( new { results = gps });
```

2.

```
return Ok(gpsJson);
```

Comment: now im gettinng records in json object. can u tell me how to get that in return.how to return gpsJson ?

Comment: The initial question was about converting list of objects to JSON. So I've posted the answer for that. Now If the concern is about returning json as HttpActionResult, I've updated the answer again.